# How to remove (and count) duplicates in an array

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm quite new to Google Apps Script (and not an engineer).

I'm working on a tool to analyze my calendar and I have an array called "events" which includes details about every meeting I had for a given time period.

I want to create a NEW array that does NOT include duplicates, but instead has a count for the number of duplicates. For example:

Events array:

```
Index: Name, Duration, Recurring?

1: "Lunch", 60, "Yes"

2: "Catchup with Tom", 30, "Yes"

3: "Quick update", 60, "No"

4: "Lunch", 60, "Yes"

5: "Catchup with Tom", 30, "Yes"
```

New array:

```
Index: Name, Duration, COUNT

1: "Lunch", 60, 2

2: "Catchup with Tom, 30, 2

3: "Quick update", 60, 1
```

I found some amazing JavaScript code that uses "reduce", but the example is for a single dimensional  array. Could it be modified to be multidimensional?

Note: in my actual code I'm comparing the "Name" of each meeting AND the "Description" to find duplicates (these are not shown in my simplified example above).

```
var ar = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
var result = ar.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e] = (r[e] || 0) + 1;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

### Update

I got some errors when I tried to run the answer from 'tehhowch' but I *think* I fixed them. Unfortunately, there's nothing in the log when I try to run my code.

Here is my new code:

```
...
var mycal = stp.getRange("B1").getValue();  // e-mail address for calendar
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

var cal_start = stp.getRange("B2").getValue(); // start date
var cal_end = stp.getRange("B3").getValue();  // end date
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(cal_start), new Date(cal_end));

var nameIndex = 0;
var descriptionIndex = 1;
var obj =[]; // Added this after answer to fix "undefined error"

var summary = events.reduce(function(obj, row) {
  var key = row[nameIndex] + ", " + row[descriptionIndex];
  obj[key] = (obj[key]++ || 0); // Fixed this line from answer?
  return obj;
}, {});
Logger.log(obj);
...
```

Comment: What have you tried? You can start by  declaring a 2D array in your example(`ar`) and modifying `e` accordingly like `e[0]`.

Comment: In the example code in your question, you're using [getEvents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime) function, which returns an array filled with [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) objects instead of the objects array you're describing with the name, duration and recurring indexes. Please clarify which "Events array" are you using and how are you getting this events array.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My initial array was just an attempt to create a simple example. My actual array IS using getEvents. So that is returning an array of objects? Hmm. I thought it was just a multidimensional array. (Still learning!)

Well, that changes things, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: What does `events` really look like?

Comment: When I use debug it shows as an array full of objects. My code mostly works with an array I create called "details". That is generated with this line of code:

var details = [events[i].getTitle(),events[i].getDescription(),events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isRecurringEvent()]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get Event List Remove Duplicates but record number of each**

```
function getUniqueEventList() {
  var mylist=[];
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById('calendar id');
  var td=new Date();
  var startTime=new Date(td.getFullYear(),td.getMonth(),td.getDate()-2);//2 days ago
  var endTime=new Date(td.getFullYear(),td.getMonth(),td.getDate()+5);//five days from now
  var events=cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
  var obj={eA:[]};
  for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    var key=events[i].getTitle()+events[i].getDescription();
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      obj[key]={title:events[i].getTitle(),description:events[i].getDescription(),start:events[i].getStartTime(),id:events[i].getId(),copies:0};
      obj.eA.push(key);
    }else{
      obj[key].copies+=1;//count the copies
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<obj.eA.length;i++) {
    mylist.push(obj[obj.eA[i]]);
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(mylist));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to make a few modifications but this seems to be working great! Much appreciated!!

Comment: Please let me know what you had to change so that I can fix the answer thanks

Comment: In my actual code I'm pulling in start and end dates from a sheet. I don't remember seeing any obvious errors in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Object keys are converted to strings when inserting/addressing a hashmap so that code will already find exact duplicates. For `reduce` of a multidimensional array, your `e` is more accurately named `row`, and `row[0]` will be its first element.

As an example:

```js
var nameIndex = 0;
var descriptionIndex = 4;

var summary = myArr.reduce(function(obj, row) {
  var key = row[nameIndex] + ", " + row[descriptionIndex];
  obj[key] = ++(obj[key] || 0);
  return obj;
}, {});
```